# Where should I ask questions about using plugins with my WordPress site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Could I have support for finding an appropriate place to ask? I am aware of wp.stackexchange.com, but they seem to focus on core WordPress (not plugin features), and is a development site (as opposed to an "I have a WordPress site. How can I do XYZ?").

For example, I have the following question:

---

### How can I get Yoast SEO + WordPress to display multilevel breadcrumbs?

When I migrated from a static site, I had breadcrumbs like:

> [CJS Hayward](https://cjshayward.com)
>   → [Orthodox Books Online, and More](https://cjshayward.com/library/) →
>   [Orthodox
>   Theology](https://cjshayward.com/library/#orthodox_theology) →
>   Doxology

Or if you'd like source,

```
<p class="breadcrumb"><a href="https://cjshayward.com" title="Official author site for CJS Hayward">CJS Hayward</a>
&rarr; <a href="https://cjshayward.com/library/" title="An online library where you can read whole books free.">Orthodox Books Online, and More</a> &rarr;
<a href="https://cjshayward.com/library/#orthodox_theology" title="Free online homilies and other Orthodox theology.">Orthodox
Theology</a> &rarr;
Doxology
</p>
```

In other words, there were multiple levels. (Please note that for the WordPress implementation, I'm intending one parent page per level of hierarchy.)

I've looked around, and I haven't found instructions to recreate this kind of breadcrumb (or something that would be better in the context).

How can I recreate this basic breadcrumb effect, or have something else that would be a better fit with WordPress + Yoast SEO?

---

Where would this be appropriate?

Comment: Looks like plenty of those questions fly on SO: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=yoast+breadcrumbs&pagesize=50 but that wouldn't be my suggestion.

Comment: I decided to [post my question on webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122787/how-can-i-get-yoast-seo-under-wordpress-to-display-multilevel-heirarchical-bread).